# iCloud Photo Sharing doesn't work on my iPhone in iOS 11

Tags: icloud, ios

I just sign out and sign in again to my iCloud account on iPhone but there is no shared albums at all. Why?

[image]

but on iPad I have all shared albums. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had/have the same thing. Mine appeared when something happened in the photo stream. So get someone to add a new picture or like/comment and then that'll push them across (Or do it yourself on the iPad)
Mine still aren't right though as I see comments with no names next to them (From people on ios 10 I assume)